# Browser tries to upgrade to HTTPS when accessing hosted server (dumb netcat binding) through domain name, but allows HTTP when using direct IP

Tags: google-chrome, https, dns, digital-ocean

I recently set up a Digital Ocean droplet and purchased a domain name. I have set up the AAAA record to point to the digital ocean droplet and have verified that the changes have propagated (for example, I can ssh to the server using the DNS name).

There is NO load balancer or firewall set up. The only digital ocean product I have set up is my droplet.

I noticed some bizarre behavior when running some tests.

I have tried several methods of serving HTTP content from the droplet, such as my personal site running in dotnet core and an express.js site.

However for this question I want to focus on the most basic example, to avoid the possibility that the request is being upgraded by a misconfigured server:

```
nc -l -p 1500 -c 'echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n HELLO"'
```

When I navigate to the my droplet through my domain name (`http://example.com:1500`) , I see the netcat process finish executing in my droplet ssh session, and Chrome tells me:

[image: Chrome Error]

**This site can’t provide a secure connection. example.com sent an invalid response. ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.**

I then see that the URL has somehow automatically changed to `https//example.com:1500`.

When I navigate to the droplet using the IP address (assuming my droplet IP is `12.34.56.78`, I go to `http://12.34.56.78:1500`), I get the expected text "HELLO" displayed in the browser.

[image: Expected Result]

This result is the same in all browsers.

Why does making http requests to my droplet attempt upgrading to https, but only when going through the domain? Is this a browser behavior or something to do with Digital Ocean?

Thanks for taking the time to check out this question.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I have a .dev tld and chrome automatically upgrades all .dev tlds to HTTPS!

https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/

This was driving me crazy.